# Grails:-How To display image in file system

Tags: image, grails

I need to display image that is in file system not in project directory in grails.. 
i used

```
< img src="${createLinkTo(dir: '/Users/ME/ddImages/reg/', file: '${userInstance.fileName}.jpg')}" alt="User Photo"/>
```

but that doesn't seem to work

so any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, the grails tag is depricated, use resource; and that tag will keep you within the application's base path

http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+createLinkTo

Documentation on the img tag
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp,

Possible values for "src"

```
An absolute URL - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/image.gif")
A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like src="image.gif")
```

Comment: yes i know it's depricated sir... but the thing is something like that.
<img src="/Users/ME/ddImages/reg/1283427613720.jpg" alt="Grails"/>
won't work for me and never get the image.. so what is the problem

Comment: You want a rendered page on the client to load an image from a directory on the server - sorry, but it doesn't work that way. The client can only load the image from an absolute or relative URL (as Aaron mentioned). Either put the images under your application, or map the directory so that it is accessible from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are trying to render a file that is not in the webroot of your project. You CAN'T do this by simply passing a URL to your view.
One way you can do it is read the image file as a stream and then write the byte stream to view. e.g:

```
<img src="${request.contextPath}/controllerName/getImage?filepath=${path_to_file_in_filesystem}" alt="whatever. alternatively, filename"/>
```

then the action in the controller will look like this:

```
def getImage(){
    def path = params.filepath
    //returns an image to display
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    def fileext = path.substring(path.indexOf(".")+1, path.length())

    ImageIO.write( originalImage, fileext, baos );
    baos.flush();

    byte[] img = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    response.setHeader('Content-length', img.length.toString())
    response.contentType = "image/"+fileext // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << img
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

That should do it. Hope this helps someone.